# Preventing jquery validation on drop down bound to int?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

I have setup globalization on my web page and have this piece of code to validate numbers:

```
$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return !isNaN($.global.parseFloat(value));
};
```

But this now also validates drop down boxes where I bind to an Nullable eg:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VendorId, Model.VendorList, "")
```

which now does not validate properly. How can I prevent this validation on the client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add data-val attribute:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VendorId, 
    Model.VendorList, "", new { data_val = "false" })
```